# Can't codesign gdb on macOS Catalina 10.15.1: unrecognized blob type

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-catalina, codesign, entitlements

I followed the steps described in https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin (and checked them [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1436370/how-to-codesign-gdb-on-os-x-mojave), they're the same)

But after I had tried to [codesign gdb via entitlements.xml](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin#Sign_and_entitle_the_gdb_binary), I got the next error:

```
gdb-entitlement.xml: unrecognized blob type (accepting blindly)
gdb-entitlement.xml: invalid length in entitlement blob
```

gdb 9.1 (from Homebrew)

Some years ago I did the same on macOS High Sierra and everything was ok, but Catalina makes life of developers more difficult.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you create *gdb-entitlement.xml* ? 
If in some text editor, try to create it in IDE. It helped me.
Source of solution:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/air/tutorial-on-publishing-flex-air-app-for-mac-app-store-or-just-using-developer-id-for-general/m-p/6120942?page=2

Comment: Using Apple's TextEdit didn't work.
Using an IDE like CLion worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin Shows the xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
</pre>
```

Remove the `</pre>` at the end.  Not sure why its there.

Comment: Thanks for your assumption, I removed it too but got the same result.
I tried to use 
`codesign -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)` with **sudo** almost everywhere and seems that it code signed. 
But after that gdb doesn't work even at simple _helloworld_ example - it just hangs